# Remove stacktrace from python gevent output

Tags: python, gevent, spawn, greenlets

I'm new to python and trying to remove/trim gevent stacktrace output when an exception is raised. I read somewhere that I can make it happen by using AsyncResult, however it seems like I can't figure out how to use this.

Here is an example I started with and iterated over to make it similar to the real code I'm troubleshooting, but I got stuck in the last phase when I tried to add my_decor to work(). 
Any help fixing this is much appreciated.

```
from gevent.event import AsyncResult
import gevent
from functools import wraps


def my_decor(k, *args, **kwargs):
    @wraps(k)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r = AsyncResult()
        try:
            value = k()
        except Exception as e:
            r.set_exception(e)
        else:
            r.set(value)
        return r.exception or r.value
    result = gevent.spawn(wrapper, k)
    return result


def f():
    def foo():
        if True:
                raise Exception('tttttttt')
    return foo


def p():
    def bar():
        if True:
                raise Exception('ppppppppppppp')
    return bar


@my_decor
def work():
    foo1 = gevent.spawn(f())
    bar1 = gevent.spawn(p())
    gevent.joinall([foo1, bar1])
    return foo1.get() or bar1.get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, figured it might be a help to those with the same problem.

```
from gevent.event import AsyncResult
import gevent
from functools import wraps


def my_decor(k):
    @wraps(k)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r = AsyncResult()
        try:
            value = k(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            r.set_exception(e)
        else:
            r.set(value)
        return r.exception or r.value
    return wrapper


def f(msg):
    @my_decor
    def foo():
        if True:
            raise Exception('tttttttt %s' % msg)
#           print('test')
    return foo


def p(msg):
    @my_decor
    def bar():
        if True:
            raise Exception('ppppppppppppp %s', msg)
    return bar


def work():
    test = "test"
    seti = "set"
    foo1 = gevent.spawn(f(test))  # returns a function that coroutine uses
    bar1 = gevent.spawn(p(seti))
    gevent.joinall([foo1, bar1])
    return foo1.get() or bar1.get()


res = work()
print res
```